# React keep a state in the highest component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, rbac

I am trying to create a React RBAC system where my backend has a field called `role: admin` for example which tells the access the user has. After a successful sign in, I direct the user to a specific route (using Protected Route) but I want to check that if the user has the clearance level (if role is admin and not general). I thought that if I keep a state where I am routing which stores the role of the user, I can check if the user has the required access and send him accordingly but I am not sure whether this is a good approach and how to do it.

App.js - RequireAuth just checks if the user session exists or not (it then redirects it to login)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   }

  render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = '/'
                component = {LandingPage}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/register'
                component = {Register}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/addBill'
                component = {RequireAuth(AddBill)}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/addItem'
                component = {RequireAuth(AddItem)}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/deleteItem'
                component = {RequireAuth(DeleteItem)}
              />
            </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

SignIn.js (I just route the user to the endpoint if it is a successful login or else display an error message)

```
if(status === 200) {
   this.props.history.push('/addItem')
}
```

RequireAuth does not have access the role of the user but I wanted to implement RBAC on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add your permission data eg : `Roles` to global App State/Store, you could do this easily with React context API.

```
//these will probably go in a file AppProvider.js
    const AppContext = React.createContext({userRole:'general', setUserRole: ()=>{}});
    
    const AppProvider = ({children}) => {
       const [userRole,setUserRole] = React.useState('general');
    
       return <AppContext.Provider value={{ userRole, setUserRole }}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
    }

//end AppProvider.js
    
    const RequireAuth = (component) => {
       const {userRole} = React.useContext(AppProvider);
       const Component = () =>  {
         //check your RBAC logic here now that you have access to userRole
       }
    
       return Component;
    }
```